# when I startup Intellij Idea 14.1,it will run some java.exe processes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

> when I startup Intellij Idea 14.1,it will  run some java.exe processes.
>   The following result

- > java.exe  4580  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\java.exe
- > java.exe  8660  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe

> I install JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7

- The following is my configuration:

> JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45

I don't know why is this? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your error? Could you share your log files and also your intellij configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

Java.exe it's a background process, includes the [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) as well as the Application Programming Interface that enables to run Java based programmes. Also read about [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).